# Python script not iterating through all objects in collections

Tags: python, modifiers

I've written a script in order to create simplified versions of objects which I will later import into Unity to form a Level Of Detail group (LOD). The script is supposed to perform the following tasks for each object of each collection in the project:

1. Rename the source object by adding "_LOD0" to its current name.
2. Duplicate the source object and rename the copy to "..._LOD1".
3. Add and apply a Decimate modifier with a 0.1 ratio.
4. Duplicate the new object and rename it to "..._LOD2".
5. Add and apply a Decimate modifier with a 0.1 ratio.

It works fine but doesn't perform the aforementioned actions for every object in the collection.

Is there something I'm missing/doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

for vl in C.scene.view_layers:
    for l in vl.layer_collection.children:
        l.exclude = False # Activate the collection
        for obj in l.collection.all_objects: # Loop through all the objects in the current collection
            # LOD0
            obj.select_set(True) # Select the object
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj # Set the selected object as the active one
            obj.name = obj.name + "_LOD0" # Rename selected object
            name_list = list(obj.name) # Create a list of all the characters in obj.name
            # LOD1
            lod1_name = ''.join((name_list[:-1] + list('1')))
            bpy.ops.object.duplicate() # Duplicate the active object
            active_obj = bpy.context.active_object # The dublicate object will be active
            active_obj.name = lod1_name
            modifier = active_obj.modifiers.new(name = "Decimate",type = 'DECIMATE') # Add a decimate modifier
            modifier.ratio = 0.1 # float in [0, 1], default 1.0
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier = "Decimate") # Apply the modifier
            # LOD2
            lod2_name = ''.join((name_list[:-1] + list('2')))
            bpy.ops.object.duplicate() # Duplicate the active object
            active_obj = bpy.context.active_object # The dublicate object will be active
            active_obj.name = lod2_name
            modifier = active_obj.modifiers.new(name = "Decimate",type = 'DECIMATE') # Add a decimate modifier
            modifier.ratio = 0.1 # float in [0, 1], default 1.0
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier = "Decimate") # Apply the modifier
            active_obj.select_set(False) # Deselect object
        l.exclude = True # Deactivate the collection
```

Here is an example of the state of the objects before...
[image: Before]

...and after the script has been run (Part.3 has not been duplicated).
[image: After]

Comment: Hello ! This looks like a classic programming gotcha. You're iterating over a list that you're modifying. Try using a copy with `for obj in l.collection.all_objects[:]:`

Comment: @Gorgious Well that was simple! Thank you!